# visual studio 2011 vs 2010 EventHandlers

Tags: visual-studio

At work we use VS 2010 but some people have vs 2011
In VS 2011 when user adds event in the designer, it is generated like this:

```
this.upDownDeleteControlProbes.ContextChanged += upDownDeleteControlProbes_ContextChanged;
```

unfortunately when code gets regenerated in VS 2010 event disappears.
is there a way to fix this?

Comment: In which designer? what kind of project are you working on?

Comment: I am working on Windows Forms Application.